# VBA Script to generate Calendar Invites from Excel - but from a Shared Calendar

Tags: vba, excel, calendar, outlook-addin

I'm NO coder and have less than an elementary base of knowledge in VBA or scripting. I pieced this code together which will take an excel spreadsheet (one meeting per row) and generate a calendar invite complete with subject, Date/Time, & attendees. This appointmentItem is being generated on my calendar, but I need it to open on a shared calendar of mine.  Caveats:  I do not know what code is needed to do this, and I do not have the knowledge to understand the format that an outlook calendar path is in. The accounts are linked to my corporate server and we do use aliases in our global directory.

```
Sub AddAppointments()

    Dim myoutlook As Object ' Outlook.Application
    Dim r As Long
    Dim myapt As Object ' Outlook.AppointmentItem

    ' late bound constants
    Const olAppointmentItem = 1
    Const olBusy = 2
    Const olMeeting = 1

    ' Create the Outlook session
    Set myoutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    ' Start at row 2
    r = 2

    Do Until Trim$(Cells(r, 1).Value) = ""
        ' Create the AppointmentItem
        Set myapt = myoutlook.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
        ' Set the appointment properties
        With myapt
            .Subject = Cells(r, 1).Value
            .Location = Cells(r, 2).Value
            .Start = Cells(r, 3).Value
            .Duration = Cells(r, 4).Value
            '.Recipients.Add Cells(r, 8).Value


            ' **Why Doesn't this Work?!?**
            .Recipients.ResolveAll



            .MeetingStatus = olMeeting
            ' not necessary if recipients are email addresses
            .AllDayEvent = Cells(r, 31).Value

            ' If Busy Status is not specified, default to 2 (Busy)
            If Len(Trim$(Cells(r, 5).Value)) = 0 Then
                .BusyStatus = olBusy
            Else
                .BusyStatus = Cells(r, 5).Value
            End If

            If Cells(r, 6).Value > 0 Then
                .ReminderSet = True
                .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = Cells(r, 6).Value
            Else
                .ReminderSet = False
            End If
            'Set body format to HTML - ** THIS DOESN'T WORK **
            '.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
            '.HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY>Enter the message text here. </BODY></HTML>"

            .Body = Cells(r, 7).Value
            .Save
            r = r + 1
            .Send
        End With
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To create an appointment on a shared calendar you need to use the [Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861028(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Items class which comes from the shared caledar folder. The [How To: Create a new Outlook Appointment item](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/04/outlook-create-appointment-item/) explains different ways of creating appointment items in Outlook. Note, you can use the [GetSharedDefaultFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869575(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Namespace class to get a shared calendar folder.

```
  ' **Why Doesn't this Work?!?**
   .Recipients.ResolveAll
```

It looks like you need to add any recipient to the Recipients collection first. For example:

```
Sub CreateAppt()  
  Dim myItem As Object  
  Dim myRequiredAttendee, myOptionalAttendee, myResourceAttendee As Outlook.Recipient 
  Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)  
  myItem.MeetingStatus = olMeeting  
  myItem.Subject = "Strategy Meeting"  
  myItem.Location = "Conference Room B"  
  myItem.Start = #9/24/2014 1:30:00 PM#  
  myItem.Duration = 90  
  Set myRequiredAttendee = myItem.Recipients.Add("Nate Sun")  
  myRequiredAttendee.Type = olRequired  
  Set myOptionalAttendee = myItem.Recipients.Add("Kevin Kennedy")  
  myOptionalAttendee.Type = olOptional  
  Set myResourceAttendee = myItem.Recipients.Add("Conference Room B")  
  myResourceAttendee.Type = olResource  
  myItem.Display  
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Eugene. Thanks for the look. I took a look at the code mentioned in the GetSharedDefaultFolder link. The description provided seems to be on target with what I'm looking for. I hate to ask for the hand-holding, but can you update my original code to include the GetSharedDefaultFolder method? I can't seem to debug it when I try to insert it. Also, I understand that I should change "Dan Wilson" to my target co-worker and then resolve the address; but what is MAPI? Should I be putting my Name in that part of the code?

Comment: Yes, you are on the right avenue. You need to change the name to target your co-worker instead. You are the organizer, not a recipient.